# Laravel: Error while import excel into database

Tags: excel, laravel

I am trying to export/import Excel files from/to the database. For that, I have viewed few tutorials. All show the same way for it. Here are the links.

- https://www.laravelcode.com/post/laravel-8-excel-and-csv-import-export-to-database-using-maatwebsite-excel-with-example
- https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-8-import-export-excel-and-csv-file-tutorialexample.html

And some other.

Exporting excel from the database is working fine. I am getting errors only while importing.

In both tutorials, they showed same way of importing code as shown below

```
public function model(array $row) {
    return new product([
        'vendor_id'    => $row[0],
        'product_name'    => $row[1],
        'product_price'    => $row[2],
        'product_model'    => $row[3],
        'created_at'    => $row[4],
        'updated_at'    => $row[5],
        ]);  
}
```

It is giving me this error while I am trying to import excel.

```
Add [vendor_id] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [App\Models\product].
```

I try to search about fillable and found some solutions. I tried to apply on it but the error isn't getting resolved. Any idea where I went wrong?

> UPDATE

Product Model file code

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class product extends Model {
   use HasFactory;
}
```

Comment: is vendor_id  added to fillable property in model ?

Comment: @JohnLobo I am new in laravel. I am not fully clear, what actually fillable mean. How do I check if it is fillable? I am able to insert/update data in `product` model in which `vendor_id` column is present.

Comment: can you share product model

Comment: @JohnLobo You mean full code of `product` model in `app->models->product.php`?

Comment: better add so some one can help you to solve or try adding protected $guarded=['id'] in product model

Comment: @JohnLobo Question updated

Comment: add this  protected $guarded=['id'] in product model

Comment: @JohnLobo wow this solve the issue. Thanks, please post answer and explain why this was needed in case of importing. Will be helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to specify either a `fillable` or `guarded` property on your `model class`. These properties are required because all `Eloquent models` are protected against `mass assignment` vulnerabilities by default.

A mass assignment vulnerability occurs when a user passes an unexpected HTTP request field and that field changes a column in your database that you did not expect. For example, a malicious user might send an is_admin parameter through an HTTP request, which is then passed to your model's create method, allowing the user to escalate themselves to an administrator.

If you are not specifying `$guarded` property then all fields need to be mentioned in `$fillable` property.

```
protected $fillable = ['vendor_id',
                       'product_name',
                       'product_price',
                       'product_model',
                      ];
```

or

```
protected $guarded=['id']
```

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment